# Post mod links broken after submitting the mod form into a new tab

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

How to reproduce:

- Open the "mod" menu of an answer that has deleted comments.
- Select "show X deleted comments"
- Middle-click the submit button to open the comments in a new tab [might be firefox-only]
- Select another option in the still-open mod menu
- Hit submit

This results in a URL such as `http://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/<id>/commentscommentsshow-flags` which is invalid and gives you a 404 error.

Apparently hitting the submit button appends the action to the current `action` of the form so it should be pretty easy to fix.

```
jForm.attr('action', jForm.attr('action') + jChecked.val());
```

I'd either store the base URL in a `data-` attribute or save it in a local variable right before binding the `submit` event for that form.